# Не отображается текст с пробелами .textContent

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Из таблицы `MySQL` получены три значения:

1. Имя: **Николай**
2. Имя: **Дмитрий**
3. Имя: **С тепан**

Когда я кликаю на первый и второй пункты - значения прекрасно выводятся в таблицу(которая находится в нижней части сайта). Если же нажать на третий пункт - клик игнорируется. Когда я убрал пробел в третьем пункте - он тоже стал выводиться в таблицу по клику.

HTML:
`<p id="name">Пусто</p>`

PHP:
`echo '<div onclick=nFull("' . $row['name'] . '")></div>';`

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function nFull(name) {
        document.getElementById('name').textContent = name;
    }
</script>
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: Клик игнорируется, или в консоли есть какая-то ошибка? После рендеринга страницы, что находится в проблемном диве (посмотреть можно либо в ViewSource либо в инспекторе)?

Comment: @AndrewParamoshkin в консоли выдает ошибку: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Посмотрите где возникает ошибка и все станет понятно. Думаю, где-то нарушается формат при инъекции PHP переменной

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что Вы рисуете не правильный `HTML`. То есть, если поглядеть, что получается у Вас, то получаем:

```
<div onclick=nFull('С тепан')></div>
```

где мы видим, что у Вас в функцию `nFull` передается строка `'С тепан'`, в которой содержится пробел. Вроде бы все хорошо, но Вы забыли еще одни кавычки:

```js
    function nFull(name) {
        document.getElementById('name').textContent = name;
    }
```

```html
<p id="name">Пусто</p>

<div onclick="nFull('Николай')">Николай</div>
<div onclick="nFull('Дмитрий')">Дмитрий</div>
<div onclick="nFull('С тепан')">С тепан</div>
```

Функцию `nFull` оберните в кавычки и все заработает. Вот так:

```
echo '<div onclick="nFull(\'' . $row['name'] . '\')"></div>';
```

Comment: что-то не работает. теперь не выдает ни одно значение. если нажать на любой из пунктов, в консоле появляется ошибка: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: @Pavel, внес правку в ответ. Должны быть одинарные кавычки, посмотрите правку.

Comment: действительно, всё работает, спасибо